# Why xml_http_request requires an action as its parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, xmlhttprequest

Requests through browsers only require its HTTP method and Rails dispatch it to a proper controller action based on defined routes. So, why `xhr` can't do it?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-xml_http_request

Following code is excerpt from [Hartl's rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users)

route definition for relationships resource

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
end

# relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)       relationships#create
# relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)   relationships#destroy
```

controller

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

a form in a view template which sends a POST request results in creating a new relationship and after creating the relationship, this form disappears and another form with "Unfollow" button appears instead.

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow" %>
<% end %>
```

This form just sends a POST request to `/relationships`. Since Rails route it to `relationships#create` (with params[:relationship][:followed_id]), there is no need to specify the action here.

spec which results in sending a POST request through a browser.

```
it "should increment the followed user count" do
  expect do
    click_button "Follow"
  end.to change(user.followed_users, :count).by(1)
end
```

**with Ajax**

form

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id),
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

spec with `xhr`

```
it "should increment the Relationship count" do
  expect do
    xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
  end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
end
```

So, I wonder why

```
xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
```

needs `:create`? I tend to think sending a POST request to `/relationship` with relevant objects is enough, even with the `xhr`.

Apparently this confusion comes from my poor understanding of how `xhr` works and the question now must be "How `xhr` works? Why `xhr` even want `:action` specified?"

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you are trying to do?  Have a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Integration/Session/xml_http_request which uses slightly more useful parameter names.

Comment: I'd surmise it's to do with the routes - HTTP requests are directed to a specific `controller/action` route; as are `xml` requests. But as an XML request has different headers, it must be handled differently. I'll have a further look into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `xhr` needs `:create` because it seems it is controller spec. Controller specs are kind of unit test, and they bypass router (unlike integration tests/request specs). As soon as router is bypasses, there is no information which action of the controller should be called in test, so you have to specify both method and action.

There is also `xhr` method defined in `ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers` to be used in integration tests (request specs):

```
xhr(request_method, path, parameters = nil, headers_or_env = nil)
```

As soon as integration tests (and request specs) are 'full-stack' tests (and are not bound to one controller), you need to provide method and path to `xhr`, and controller/action would be determined by router.

Hope it answers your question.